# How to distribute Traffic between two micro services when it is called from third service based on TPS Percentage

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, load-balancing, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix-ribbon

Detailed Requirement : If there are two services say A and B and we want to distribute traffic in 10% & 90% basis then 10% of traffic should get routed to Service-A & 90% to Service-B from service C

We tried this with Netflix Ribbon but to get the Real Time TPS was a problem and to manage the loadbalance between two services was doubtful. As per our understanding : The call to microservices can be directed to multiple instances in Netflix Ribbon.

Please suggest if there is any other approach which we can try out.